# API call is working fine when called through Postman, but when called by the web page it bogs and returns failed

Tags: laravel-5

I have a laravel application that I'm creating. The web routes calls the API for information. When I test my API it returns data, but when the front end dev calls the API it slows the system and returns a failure. This is a simple GET that was working before but is not working now.

This is the the API call from the web:

```
$url = 'http://localHost:8000/api/v1.0/theater_movies';
$opts = array('http'=>array('http' => array(
    'protocol_version' => 1.1,
    'user_agent'       => 'PHPExample',
    'method'           => 'GET',
    'header'           => "Content-type: application/json\r\n")
));
//Basically adding headers to the request
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$getMovies = json_decode(file_get_contents($url,false,$context), true);
```

I'm getting the file_get_contents error:
file_get_contents(http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/theater_movies): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

And this is the correct output from Postman
[image: The Postman results]

Comment: What is the reason you are using 'localhost' in your api call but in Postman you use 'bloodangel-primus' ?

Comment: The web server is being hosted on the same machine as the API so it is talking to itself, localhost, my dev machine is not on the same machine so it's talking to a different machine, Bloodangel-primus.